# How to set io.output() back to default output file?

Tags: lua, io

I am learning how work with files in Lua, and I came across a problem.

I know that:

- io.output() allows me to specify the file that I will write output to.
- The io.write() function simply gets a number of string arguments and writes them to the current output file.
- io.close() then closes the file I am reading or writing on.

I first set io.output() to "myNewFile.txt" then I did io.write("Hello World!").

`io.output("myNewFile.txt")`
`io.write("Hello World!")`

This part worked well and myNewFile.txt got Hello World written to it.
Then I wrote `io.close()` to close the myNewFile.txt.

After that, I wrote `io.write("Hello World!")`, but I got an error:

`C:\\Program Files\\lua\\lua54.exe: ...OneDrive\\Documents\\learning lua\\steve's teacher\\main.lua:9: default output file is closed stack traceback: \[C\]: in function 'io.write' ...OneDrive\\Documents\\learning lua\\steve's teacher\\main.lua:9: in main chunk \[C\]: in ?`

I wanted `io.write("Hello World!")` to write Hello World in the terminal. I know can use print() but print() function adds extra characters like \n and things like that.

So my question is, how do I write Hello World in the terminal using io.write("Hello World!") in this situation?

I tried to search this error up on Google, but there weren't any results. I also tried joining many Discord servers, but I didn't get a proper response.  I am a new developer to Lua so this all is really confusing to me.

Comment: Because i am using Lua to learn how to script in roblox

Comment: Consider rewriting your code to not change the global output file descriptor. Instead you should be opening a file using `local file = io.open("filename")`, then writing using `file:write("string")`, and then closing using `file:close()`. For closing, you might have to take care with error handling, but you can worry about that later on.

Comment: so instead of reading the Lua manual you join Discord servers, search the web and write SO posts, hoping to find people who have?

Comment: @LMD and Piglet thank you both so much for helping. I am new to Lua coding so I am messing up a lot but thank you for giving me feedback

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After `io.close()` do a `io.output(io.stdout)` to set it back.

The clean way

```
local oldout = io.output() -- without argument returns actual output
io.output("file") -- set to a filename
-- do file operations here
-- use io.flush() where it is necessary
io.close() -- close file also do a flush()
io.output(oldout) -- set back to oldout ( normally io.stdout )
-- changing io.output() back should also close() and flush() the "file"
-- But better doublecheck this when using userdata without experience
```

Comment: From the reference manual: "The table io also provides three predefined file descriptors with their usual meanings from C: io.stdin, io.stdout, and io.stderr. The I/O library never closes these files." - even though `io.output("file")` is invoked, `io.stdout` will remain open.

Comment: I am using this fast file handling too for my SRT function ( Subtitlegenerator ) - I am not sure but if used io.output("file") in a Function than outside the Function it is automatically set back to io.stdout - Its worth a try - Also io.close() is not sooo important than io.flush() ;-)